# C++ - Using #include directives to change program configuration in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, include

I have used an Arduino with my electric circuit. The circuit is still a prototype and I am still changing it and trying new *Configurations*. That means that on each run, I would like a different version of double measurePower() to be executed. Call it Polymorphism, if you will.

So far, I have done the following, to change the configuration on demand, by changing only one line:

***main.c:***

```
#include config.h
```

***config.h:***

```
#include circuit_1.h // change this to circuit_i.h, whenever you want.
// define var1, var2, ...
```

***circuit_1.h:***

```
double measurePower() {
    // calculate based on some config.
}
```

***circuit_2.h:***

```
double measurePower() {
    // calculate based on another config.
}
```

But after running into #include related errors, and looking online, I realize that this is not the best Idea. So my question is, how can I keep Polymorphism, and also possibly keep the compiled executable smaller. So, is there a practical solution using directives only?

Comment: `#ifdef SOMETHING #include 1.h #else #include 2.h #endif`. Also this is not polymorphism.

Comment: Of course THIS is not polymorphic. But in essence, it is a Polymorphism problem. And it could be solved by Object Oriented C++ Polymorphism. like so: AbstractCircuit.h, FirstCircuit.h extends AbstractCircuit, SecondCircuit extends AbstractCircuit.h ... and different implementations and methods for each class of Circuit there is out there.

Comment: In general, Is it Ok if you include a header in another header? I have read recommendations against that.

Comment: Having as few includes in headers as possible is always good, but of course you should do it when you need it.